# How to convert IdentityServer4-mongo-AspIdentity from .net core 1.x to 2.1

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, openid-connect

Im trying migrate code from project IdentityServer4-mongo-AspIdentity (.net core 1.x) to my IdentityServer. On this moment I fix all errors in VS and app is running but when ConfigureServices is executing I have this exception:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj0xd.png)

I think problem is in this method, some ideas ?

```
public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddMongoDbForAspIdentity<TIdentity, TRole>(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder, IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot) where
        TIdentity : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDB.IdentityUser where TRole : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDB.IdentityRole
    {

        //User Mongodb for Asp.net identity in order to get users stored
        var configurationOptions = configurationRoot.Get<ConfigurationOptions>();
        var client = new MongoClient(configurationOptions.MongoConnection);
        var database = client.GetDatabase(configurationOptions.MongoDatabaseName);



        // Configure Asp Net Core Identity / Role to use MongoDB
        builder.Services.AddSingleton(x =>
        {
            var usersCollection = database.GetCollection<TIdentity>("Identity_Users");
            IndexChecks.EnsureUniqueIndexOnNormalizedEmail(usersCollection);
            IndexChecks.EnsureUniqueIndexOnNormalizedUserName(usersCollection);
            return new UserStore<TIdentity>(usersCollection);
        });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton(x =>
        {
            var rolesCollection = database.GetCollection<TRole>("Identity_Roles");
            IndexChecks.EnsureUniqueIndexOnNormalizedRoleName(rolesCollection);
            return new RoleStore<TRole>(rolesCollection);
        });
        builder.Services.AddIdentity<TIdentity, TRole>();


        return builder;
    }
```